# Dynamically grow UIView containing a non-scrollable vertical UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uiview, uicollectionview

I am looking for a way to build a UICollectionView with a vertical flow layout that is embedded in a UIView. the UIView acts as the datasource/delegate for the containing collectionview. The behavior I am looking for is that the collectionview itself has its scroll disabled and the containing UIView grows as you add more rows to the collectionview. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by following steps,

- Embed the UIView which you currently have into a UIScrollView(Make its constraint respective to its super view).
- Then add height constraint to your UIView and **create an outlet for that height constraint in our view controller**, so as of now when the height of UIView gets increased the scrollView content size will also get increased.
- Then place the UICollectionView inside the UIView and make its top, bottom, left & right constraints to UIView.
- Now increase the height constraint constant value based on the number of collection view cells in the collection view.

I hope this will work for your scenario.
But if in case you are free to explain why you need to achieve this kind of behaviour it would be nice, because I cannot able to figure out the need for it.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is a To: recipient field like you seen in an email client's compose screen. I want to add little bubbles for contacts as the user  types email addresses and have the view expand as more bubbles are added as opposed to the collectionview scrolling

Comment: @JohnBaum : Nice, thanks for sharing, I look forward to the approach which satisfies your need.

Comment: I don't quite understand the role of the scroll view in your response. Why can't I just have a collectionview directly constraint to top, left, right inside a UIView and somehow make that work?

Comment: @JohnBaum : Yes it should work as per your above comment, I took your question in another view. If it works you can update the answer also.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of scenario could be achieved. Here is rule of the thumb:
**You should not specify height of you view, that will be contains unscrollable collection, pinned to it, and it should be embedded in UIScrollView using equals width, and pinned to all sides with margin**. Auto layout makes things work.

Otherwise, is there any important reason to disable scrolling and make UIView delegate / data source for collection?

Comment: What's the role of the scroll view in your approach? Could you provide some sample code to achieve this effect?

Comment: At least one scrollable element. It needs if size of collection view and, therefore, of your view will be greater than screen size